# DXA Java 1.7: Options to debug webapp performance?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

We are currently in finalizing the DXA implementation for our customer and we are facing a performance issue by opening the website for the first time.

Are there any configs or logback classpathes we can activate to have an additional performance level logging to debug a little more than normal?

With current normal logging, the developers cannot figure out what part of DXA framework is currently causing this load/performance gap.

Maybe there is also a possibility to activate/deactivate more logging for single components on the page?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide a bit more details to what you exactly mean with "opening the website for the first time". Is it really just the first page load that is too slow (and what is too slow), and is performance after that fine or something different, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The first request **to a publication** requires downloading & parsing of a lot of binary files with publication configuration. This happens in `LocalizationFactoryImpl` class.

The only option to accelerate this is probably to somehow preload those binaries.